# Adding doxygen comments for a file included using #include inside a namespace

Tags: c++, include, documentation, doxygen

I have two files that I include using #include directive.

```
///-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
///
/// @file MyInterface.h
///
/// @brief A file containing the interface to MyInterface
///
/// @copyright Copyright (c) xxxxxxxxxx
///
///-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace MyInterface
{

   #include ../test/fileA.h
   #include ../test/fileB.h
};
```

I am getting the following error

```
FileA.h:4: warning: the name `FileA.h' supplied as the second argument in the \file statement is not an input file
FileB.h:4: warning: the name `FileB.h' supplied as the second argument in the \file statement is not an input file
```

I am assuming that this is due to lack of doxygen comments for the files included using `#include`.

How do I add doxygen comments for the same ?

Comment: Didn't you forget quotes or angle brackets around the file paths of `#include`?

Comment: In general, it's not prohibited to denote the `#include` "anywhere". The C pre-processor is not aware of namespaces - it just copies the file contents replacing the `#include`. However, it's considered as bad style as it makes the contents of the included file context dependent, and this may result in surprising and hard-to-find errors, especially for other readers.

Comment: [Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0fbdceb219094e8)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat - what do you mean when you say angle brackets around paths of include?

Comment: My other concerns aside: Syntactically correct would be either `#include <../test/fileA.h>` (with angle brackets) or `#include "./test/fileA.h"` (with quotes). [Source file inclusion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/include)

Comment: Maybe, I focused too much on C++. Doxygen provides its own commands to refer to other files. It runs a C pre-processor as well but has additional commands - usually in comments (beyond the scope of the C++ compiler). Nevertheless, I believe you can use plain mark-down files as well. Of course, I would suffix those with `.md` (instead of `.cc` or `.h`) to prevent strange maintenance issues... FYI: [Doxygen - @include](https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html#cmdinclude)

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? when I run doxygen (1.9.3 (c0b9eafbfb53286ce31e75e2b6c976ee4d345473)) with the provided source file and a clean Doxyfile I don't get any warning and the resulting documentation looks OK. Doxygen complains here about the files `FileA.h` and `FileB.h` what is in these files? Regarding the inclusion of files one has to distinguish between the C / Cpp includes in the source code, as noted by @Scheff'sCat, these are handled by doxygen in the normal way and the doxygen include command that are in the comments.